# Jquery Script Issue with add/remove class in IE7

Tags: jquery

I have "displayNone" class in my HTML, in Jquery I add and remove it and it is working with FF and IE8, but I have problem with IE7 could you help me.

```
<tr id="tr<%=category %>_1_<% =message.MessageID.ToString() %>" class='<%= (firstCategory ? "" : "displayNone") %>'>
                                    <td id="td<%=category %>_1_1_<% =message.MessageID.ToString() %>" rowspan="2">
                                        <img id="imgEnv<% =message.MessageID.ToString() %>" src='../../Content/Images/envelope_<% =(newMessage ? "closed" : "open") %>.gif'
                                            alt="message" />
                                    </td>                                  
                                    <td class="text-align-right" rowspan="2">
                                        <%= Html.CheckBox("chkMsg", false, new { @value= message.MessageID, @id = string.Format("chkMsg{0}", message.MessageID), @tabindex = "-1" })%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>



 $('a[id*=lCateg]').click(function() {
                var category = this.id.replace('lCateg', '');
                if ($('#imgCateg' + category).attr('src').indexOf('plus.gif') >= 0) {
                    $('tr[id*=' + category + '_]').removeClass('displayNone');
                    $('#imgCateg' + category).attr('src', $('#imgCateg' + category).attr('src').replace('plus.gif', 'minus.gif'));
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using jquerys built in .show .hide functions. This way it will add inline styles and you won't have any problems with any browsers :)

```
 $('a[id*=lCateg]').click(function() {
            var category = this.id.replace('lCateg', '');
            if ($('#imgCateg' + category).attr('src').indexOf('plus.gif') >= 0) {
                $('tr[id*=' + category + '_]').show();
                $('#imgCateg' + category).attr('src', $('#imgCateg' + category).attr('src').replace('plus.gif', 'minus.gif'));
            }
```